# Finder error -50 when moving files from external NTFS hard disk

Tags: finder, error, ntfs

As per title, I'm using a external NTFS hard disk for storage (guess it doesn't matter the type, but I can give more informations if needed). It happen many times, however, that I receive Finder error -50

> The operation could not be completed.
>   An unexpected error occurred (error code -50).

when trying to remove files (it also happen when move files from the external hd to the local one, dragging and dropping with cmd pressed). 
I read on the web that it may be related to illegal characters in files' names, however it seems to happen also for files that have nothing "strange" in the name (i.e. `asdf.txt`).

Besides, when the popup appears, the file gets deleted even if I cancel the operation.

I'm using MacOS 10.7.4 and Paragon NTFS 9.0.1 for enabling NTFS read/write.

Any idea of what may be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might expect, it is an error copying between disparate file systems. [This is a link](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20831?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to a very old Apple Support Document. It does however, give you the shell script to handle the copy/delete from terminal.

Another possible solution is this app: [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) instead of Paragon.

Comment: The Apple document is not very helpful, since it just suggests to copy the files, while the problem arises when I try to to remove them (also when I move them, since moving includes a remove step). I will try Tuxera.

Comment: Yes, I think Tuxera a better option. You could substitute "rm" for "cp" but you'd really, really need to be careful, as you can delete more than you wanted.